Adding special tokens to beginning and end of ngram function
I'm writing a function to that takes in text and converts the text into ngrams based on the order, n. So for bigrams n=2, fivegrams n=5, and so on. I'm trying to add special tokens at the beginning and end. I need to put n-1 special tokens in the beginning, and 1 special token at the end.
This is my function, and it works perfectly fine except I don't know a good way to add the special tokens that I mentioned above:
def create_ngrams(tokens, n):
    n_grams = ngrams(tokens, n)
    start = '<s>'
    end = '</s>'
    

    ## FIGURE OUT HOW TO ADD SPECIAL TOKENS BASED ON THE ORDER, n
        
    return [grams for grams in n_grams]

This is what its currently outputting:
[('1609', 'sonnets'),
 ('sonnets', 'william'),
 ('william', 'shakespeare'),
 ('shakespeare', '1'),
 ('1', 'fairest'),
 ('fairest', 'creatures'),
 ('creatures', 'desire'), ...

but for a bigram, n=2, I want it to look like this:
[('<s>', '1609'),
 ('1609', 'sonnets'),
 ('sonnets', 'william'),
 ('william', 'shakespeare'),
 ('shakespeare', '1'),
 ('1', 'fairest'),
 ('fairest', 'creatures'), ...

of course, it would have one ending token, </s>, as well but I just copied the beginning.
I need it to work for other ngram orders as well, I just used n=2 as an example.
NOTE: I understand that I can use the left_pad parameter of the ngram function to get them in the beginning, but I cant figure out how to get just 1 end token since the right_pad parameter also puts n-1 end tokens, so I'd like to do this without those parameters.
